# jQuery function looping again and again

Tags: javascript, jquery, fadein, fadeout

I want to create an animation where with scrolling background image of the Website changes. Changing happens with a fadeIn and fadeOut effect, But fading effect happens multiple times due to scroll function.

### [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vhhhz9t8/)

```
Jquery Code: 
var styles01 = {"background" : "url(https://iso.500px.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/cover.jpg) fixed",
                 "background-size":"cover"}; 
var styles02 = {"background" : "url(http://www.mybligr.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/beautiful-lake-wallpaper-nature-photos-pics-images-pictures-16.jpg) fixed",
            "background-size":"cover"};
var styles03 = {"background" : "url(https://cdn.fodors.com/ee/files/slideshows/9-derwent-water-lake-district-england.jpg) fixed",
            "background-size":"cover"};

$(window).scroll( function() {
 if ($(window).scrollTop() >= 50 && $(window).scrollTop() <= 150) {
     $(".wrap").fadeOut(200);
    $(".wrap").css(styles01);
     $(".wrap").fadeIn(200);
  } 
 if ($(window).scrollTop() >= 150 && $(window).scrollTop() <= 250) {
      $(".wrap").fadeOut(200);
    $(".wrap").css(styles02);
       $(".wrap").fadeIn(200);
  }
 if ($(window).scrollTop() < 50) {
     $(".wrap").fadeOut(200);
    $(".wrap").css(styles03);
      $(".wrap").fadeIn(200);
  }
});
```

Comment: without giving me a minus can somebody please help me ...

Comment: Add clauses if a style has already been loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears to be a timing issue, because you're trying to re-style and re-fade before the initial fade-out is done.  This is an asynchronous operation:

```
$(".wrap").fadeOut(200);
```

So anything that needs to happen *after* this operation should be placed in its callback, not placed immediately after this line of code.  Something like this:

```
$(".wrap").fadeOut(200, function () {
    $(".wrap").css(styles01);
    $(".wrap").fadeIn(200);
});
```

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vhhhz9t8/1/).

Comment: Thank you, I used this way . But the problem was in the example it was like this . 
$(".wrap").fadeOut( function () {
    $(".wrap").css(styles01);
    $(".wrap").fadeIn(200);
},200); this is wrong rite ?

Comment: @silvachathura: What do you mean?  Is there still a problem of some kind?

Comment: no its working thank you .. I wanted to correct my mistake